Nextjs Prisma orderby price and price is relational schema with product
There is my prisma product schemas i want to order products by price but i tried all ways still i got errors
and there is my function getProducts and order functions i can order by createdAt but price order gives me errrors
model Product {
price ProductPrice[]
createdAt DateTime @default(now())
updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model ProductPrice {
id String @id @default(uuid())
product_id String
product Product @relation(fields: [product_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
currency String
price Float
discount_price Float
createdAt DateTime @default(now())
updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

 const GENERATE_SORT_RULE = (sort) => {
    switch (sort) {
      case "price-asc":
        return [
          {
            price: {
              price: "asc",
            },
          },
        ]
      case "price-desc":
        return {
          price: {
            _desc: "desc",
          },
        };
      case "newest":
        return { createdAt: "desc" };
      case "oldest":
        return { createdAt: "asc" };
      default:
        return { createdAt: "desc" };
    }
  }

 const productByCategory = await prisma.category.findMany({
    where: {
      translations: {
        some: {
          slug,
          lang,
        },
      },
    },
    select: {
      products: {
        select: {
          price: {
            select: { price: true, currency: true },
            where: {
              currency: currency,
            },
          },
       }
        },
        orderBy: GENERATE_SORT_RULE(sort),
      },
    }
  })

HOW CAN I ORDER BY PRICE QUANTITY THERE IS MUST BE EASY
